# 24vdc variable circuit with analog input(0-10 vdc)

Tags: operational-amplifier

Im trying to find electronic circuit that powered with 24vdc.  An input 0-10 vdc analog signal.  And gives me an output 24vdc variable (0-24) vdc

Comment: Your question is kind of vague.  Are you trying to build an amplifier?

Comment: True but iwant change the out value by analog input (0-10) vdc

Comment: True but I want to change the outout value by analog lnput (0-10) vdc

Answer (score 1):

The electronic circuit which you are looking for is called as an **amplifier**,and here is a simple example for the same and may be an answer for your question

[image]

The opamp has Vs+ as 30V and Vs- as 30V which is not show in the figure

[image: That Vs+ and Vs- is the power supply for the OPAMP]

That Vs+ and Vs- is the power supply for the OPAMP

hope this helps

Comment: The OP stated that the power supply he had was 24V.

Comment: with 24v source you wont be able to get 24v amplification i think cos opamp is not ideal we can get only 90% of its max voltages so if you use 30V you can get output around 27V

Answer (score 0):

The 24V supply is limiting when you need a 0-24V DC output voltage so I would consider using a converter such as the [TES 2-2423H](http://www.tracopower.com/products/browse-by-category/show/dc-dc-converters/smd-package/tes-2h/1/) from Traco Power. It will produce +/- 15 volt rails to power a target amplifier (probably an op-amp) and costs around £10 in the UK.

There can be other options such as using two single-output isolated converters to produce (say) 3V3 dc - one can be used to make a -3V3 power rail relative to 0V and the other can be added in series with the 24V to make a 27.3 volt rail thus, you can power the op-amp for a -3V3 rail and a +27.3 volt rail.

Alternatively you roll your own flyback converter using say this sort of design: -

[image]

The one above only generates +/-12V so a small change in the transformer rattio would give you +/-15V. As for the op-amp virtually any will do but make sure they can operate from a 30V rail: -

[image]

Circuit taken from [here](http://sparksandflames.com/p72.html)